# Passing Credit Card Information via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, ssl

I am wondering if this is a secure way to process credit card information. The site uses PHP and  IS using an SSL Certifacate, but instead of submitting a form and getting $_POST variables. I want to try to use JQUERY AJAX and communicate with the user if their information was approved or not. But I am worried about if this method is secure. And example of my code is below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_process_credit_card.php", 
    data: { cardnumber : cardnumber , cardexpmonth : cardexpmonth, cardexpyear: cardexpyear, chargetotal: chargetotal, ordertype: ordertype  },
        success: function(msg){  

    $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){   

     if(msg == 'APPROVED'){

          complete_registration();
     }
     else // ERROR?
     {
     var error_message= msg;

       $('#error_message').html(error_message);

     }  

     });  

     }  

      });
```

Would this be ok?

Comment: looks fine, its just as secure as not using ajax, as long as your using an SSL connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you use HTTPS it doesn't really matter. Just ensure you use POST so the data never appears in an access log.

Note that you should get PCI certified if you are dealing with credit card data. Or maybe let another company deal with it and avoid all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX methods are actually doing an HTTP POST behind the scenes, as your type is set to POST.

Be sure to do all connections over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to the same site and you are posting to https, not to the http equivalent then I don't see how it could be any less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the URL of your page was server over HTTPS and that the URL your AJAX query is requesting is also server over HTTPS the communication should be just as secure as it would be if you were using a normal post0back to that same URL.

Just make sure that the URL you're posting to is server over HTTPS. On the server side you could also check that the request was made over HTTPS and reject any requests that were not..